# Why did Tor quietly dropped suggestion to use HTML5 to watch video in youtube? Is some new leak or problem discovered?

Tags: information-leaks, html5

Looking at Tor suggestions of how to watch youtube video, one has observed that the suggestion to use HTML5 to watch youtube video is quietly disappeared. Is some type of new leak, problem, and/or anonymity/security compromise with respect to HTML5 have been discovered?

Comment: Where was this information/suggestion written?

Comment: @JensKubieziel Dear Jens, As I remember it used to be here: https://www.torproject.org/download/download.html#warning  ,But it is not there anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [download page](https://www.torproject.org/download/download.html) had a warning, that you should visit https://www.youtube.com/html5 and enable HTML5 support. So you do not need flash to watch YouTube videos. However right now YouTube works without going first to this site. So this warning as removed with [commit `cb22dc9595d7c70c60d6cddf37c8b217a631fefc`](https://gitweb.torproject.org/project/web/webwml.git/commit/?id=cb22dc9595d7c70c60d6cddf37c8b217a631fefc).

Now you can directly go to https://youtube.com and watch a video without Flash.